# 日本語に違和感: 日本版サイトなのに「できる限り正しい英語の綴りと文法を」

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語, ヘルプ

> ヘルプ センター > 質問にあたって
> 質問が品質基準を満たしていないというメッセージが表示されるのはなぜですか?
> https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error

で質問の要件として

> - できる限り正しい英語の綴りと文法を使用してください。

が挙げられているのは、日本版にそぐわない内容であり明らかに違和感があります。
日本版で「質問が品質基準を満たしていない」メッセージが出るか出ないかはともかくとして、もし FAQ に書くとすれば

> - できるだけ分かりやすい日本語で書いてください。

ではないかと思います。

---

追記：
同様の問題点がありました。
その１：

> ヘルプ センター > 回答にあたって
> 私のアカウントからの回答が受け付けられなくなったのはなぜですか?
> https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans

において

> #### 回答禁止はどうしたら解けますか?

のなかでの条件項目で

> - できる限り正しい綴りと文法を使用してください。

という項目があります。

これも上記と同様に

> - できるだけ分かりやすい日本語で書いてください。

としたほうが良いと思います。

---

その２：

> ヘルプ センター > 回答にあたって
> 良い回答を書くには?
> https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

において

> #### 全力を尽くして書いてください。

以下の段落に

> ただし、正しい綴り、句読点、文法を使えば読みやすくなります。

と記載されています。

日本語の文章に対して「綴り」と表現されることに違和感があります。
例えば（一例です）

> ただし、読む側のことを考えた、分かりやすい文章が好ましいでしょう。

などに変更してみてはどうでしょうか。

---

以上3件に関してご検討よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: +1 英語で綴りや文法について言及しているところを，日本語で「わかりやすい日本語」に書き換えているのは妙案だと思います．

Answer (score 1):

適用しました：

- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer